# git rebase messy devel branch

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a devel branch on Github with 1500 commits and they need to be rebased into perhaps 50 commits to closer resample features.

The commits are messy in that, one feature wasn't developed fully before new commits came from another feature.

Rebasing and fixing indentation will have to be done collaboratively.

Some of the [GUIs](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) looks really great with DnD, but can they share the project, so everyone is working on the same and see the process another person have done?

**Question**

Are there a cross platform Git GUI that would be suited for such a task?

Comment: I think the bigger problem is just managing such a large number of commits together.